# Unable to create a GCP account. The option for the country China is not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, great-firewall-of-china

I am trying to help a friend who would like to sign up for a GCP account,he is located in China. And he said that the option for the country upon the creation of the account shows all other country exempt for China. Why and how can we proceed?

Comment: This looks sort of off-topic for SO, maybe try the [GCP support hub](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP does not yet offer the services directly in China due to international laws and regulations. For additional details about the how some restrictions came in, you can visit these pages 1 , 2 (May 2011).

To help your friend, I suggest that he contact one of GCP's technological partners on this pages 3 or 4. Under partnership program, they can be assisted to register an account through them.

Links:
- http://www.google.com/transparencyreport/traffic/
- https://support.google.com/transparencyreport/answer/7381384?hl=en 
- https://cloud.google.com/partners/technology-partners 
- https://cloud.withgoogle.com/partners/?search=china&sort-type=RELEVANCE